# How to read xml from url C#

Tags: c#, xml

I can't read xml string from `http://158.58.185.214/Applications/Operator/Files/Data/Bus/CityList.xml` and i think the encoding is the problem please help to solve it.

my code is:

```
        string url = "http://158.58.185.214/Applications/Operator/Files/Data/Bus/CityList.xml";
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string xml = client.DownloadString(url);
```

but the xml string is:

```
‹      í½`I–%&/mÊ{JõJ×àt¡€`$Ø@ìÁˆÍæ’ìiG#....
```

Comment: Please explain exactly what problem you are having including any errors and supply the code you are using.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem - that *exact* code works fine for me.

Comment: xml is getting fetched. No problems this side too

Comment: I can reproduce this problem on my end. XML is just garbage when retrieved via code but fine in the browser.

Comment: but not get the correct result

Comment: it can be encoding issue, look that Cities are in Arabic... but You should definitely use XmlReader Class

Comment: @Lightning3: No, there's no need to use `XmlReader` here.

Comment: @CathalMF: What code did you use to reproduce it? Just the code in the question? I had that plus `Console.WriteLine(xml)` and it was fine. This is very odd...

Comment: Yes i used the exact same code as posted and used Console.WriteLine too.

Comment: That url returns a 404, so it's hard to tell what the file is encoded with

Answer (score -1):

your problem can be solve like this

using System.Xml;

```
String URLString = " http://localhost/books.xml";
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader (URLString);

    while (reader.Read()) 
    {
    // Do some work here on the data.
     Console.WriteLine(reader.Name);
    }
Console.ReadLine();
```

refer this:https://support.microsoft.com/kb/307643/en-us

Comment: That is when reading from a local file. He is trying to download from a remote location.

Comment: this error is occured: hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.